# Пробелы после каждой буквы при вводе/выводе в VS

Tags: visual-studio, input, вывод, кириллица, visual-studio-for-mac

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: после каждой буквы, введенной/выведенной на кириллице в консоль, автоматически ставиться пробел.
Прикрепляю пример:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на фото, с латиницей таких проблем не наблюдается. Без понятия, что мне стоит делать в сложившейся ситуации. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

PS у меня установлена последняя версия VS для Mac.

Comment: гуглите на тему utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Скачай VS for Mac (Preview). Общался с поддержкой - обещали поправить в первью версии (и сделали это). А вот стабильную версию не исправили.